# setting up config server setup for mongo query router

Tags: mongodb

I am using mongo v3.2 - I already have the config replica set as well as two shard replica sets running.  When I try to launch the mongos (query router) with the test config file setting below, I get the error copied below - any ideas on how to fix this?

```
sharding:
   configDB: config-set0/127.0.0.1:27019,127.0.0.1:27020,127.0.0.1:27021
```

**error**

```
Unrecognized option: sharding.configDB
```

I can see this setting in the mongodb docs at the URL below:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-shard-cluster/

Comment: pilot error - I was running the server with mongod instead of mongos command.  Running with mongos works

Comment: Well, you could well remove the question then...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ensure that the process is being launched as mongos and not mongod if the intent is to run the process as a query router (and not a config server or a shard).

Answer (score 2):

Use this command to start the mongos.

sudo mongos -f <-- location of conf file -->